# How to add typescript typings to NPM module that exports a class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings

I would like my [design-systems-utils](https://github.com/mrmartineau/design-system-utils) module to include Typescript typings even though the source code is not written using Typescript (I have seen that others have done this).

I have already attempted this [here](https://github.com/mrmartineau/design-system-utils/blob/types/src/index.d.ts), but it does not work. By the way, my module exports a class...

```
declare class DesignSystem {
    constructor(system: object, options?: object);
    multiply(initial: number, multiplier: number): any;
    get(val: string): any;
    bp(bp: string): any;
    z(z: string): any;
    fontSize(size: string|number, toPxl?: boolean): string;
    fs(size: string|number, toPxl?: boolean): string;
    spacing(index: number): string;
    space(index: number): string;
    toPx(value: number, base: number, unit?: string): string;
    pxTo(value: number, base: number): string;
    color(hue:string, value:string): string;
    designSystem: object;
    interface options {
        defaultUnit: string,
        useModularScale: boolean,
        fontSizeUnit: string
    }
}
```

I have also seen that I should be exporting this as a module, like so:

```
declare module "DesignSystem" {
    export default class DesignSystem {
        constructor(system: object, options?: object);
        /*~ Multiply two items together */
        multiply(initial: number, multiplier: number): any;
        get(val: string): any;
        bp(bp: string): any;
        z(z: string): any;
        fontSize(size: string|number, toPxl?: boolean): string;
        fs(size: string|number, toPxl?: boolean): string;
        spacing(index: number): string;
        space(index: number): string;
        toPx(value: number, base: number, unit?: string): string;
        pxTo(value: number, base: number): string;
        color(hue:string, value:string): string;
        designSystem: object;
    }
}
```

But that also does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principal:

```
declare module "DesignSystem" { ...}
```

should be changed to the name of your npm module:

```
declare module "design-systems-utils" { ...}
```

This is the way you tell typescript "Here are the types for when the user does 'import ... from design-systems-utils'". This is mostly useful when you need to extend library types from "outside".

However, since your package.json has `types: src/index.d.ts` field, we don't even need that. Typescript already knows what library your `d.ts` file provides definition for.

```
export default class DesignSystem {...}
```

should be enough.

Your first attempt declares a *global* class called DesignSystem.  The general rule of thumb is that your `d.ts` should mirror you js structure. So if you do `export default` from js file, do it also from `d.ts`

(Also, thanks for providing definitions for your library, you make the world a better place)

Comment: Thanks Aviad, with your help, the types are working now